# Compare and Add / Update Values in an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I create a new `JSON` array in jquery with comparing existing array? if the array value exists then change the value or if new then push the new value

```
$(document).on('change','#orderedMedicines',function(){

    Medicines=$('#orderedMedicines').val(); /* Multiple Select Array */

    medicineOrderList       /* Existing Json Array */
    /* [{medicineName: "medicine1 ", quantity: 5, stock: "50.00"},{medicineName: "medicine2 ", quantity: 10, stock: "50.00"}] */

    var newMedicineOrderList=[]; /* New Json Array */

    for(var i=0;i<Medicines.length;i++){

        /* Push into new array  but check with exist array if duplicates medicineName then want to get this stock and push instead of 0 in new array */
        newMedicineOrderList.push({
            medicineName: medicineWithUnits[Medicines[i]],
            quantity: 0,
            stock:medicineWithStock[Medicines[i]]
        }); 

    }   

});
```

Comment: You do not need jQuery for this operation. Look into `Array.map`. Also, `Medicines` is not an array. Its a string

Comment: please post somewhere part of the `medicineOrderList` just to see what structure it has

Comment: you are looping on a string `Medicines` instead of an array .

Comment: There is no JSON anywhere in your question. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. Your "Json Arrays" are simply arrays.

Comment: Medicines is a multi select array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implements your own compare function

```
function indexOfMedecine(o,arr) {    
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].x == o.medicineName && arr[i].quantity == o.quantity && arr[i].stock == o.stock) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

and use it :

```
$(document).on('change', '#orderedMedicines', function() {
    Medicines = $('#orderedMedicines').val(); /* Multiple Select Array */

    medicineOrderList       /* Existing Json Array */

    var newMedicineOrderList=[]; /* New Json Array */

    for(var i=0;i<Medicines.length;i++){

    /* Push into new array  but check with exist array if duplicates medicineName then want to get this stock and push instead of 0 in new array */
    var newMed = {
          medicineName: medicineWithUnits[Medicines[i]],
          quantity: 0,
          stock:medicineWithStock[Medicines[i]]
    } 
    if(indexOfMedecine(newMed,newMedicineOrderList) < 0){
      newMedicineOrderList.push(newMed);
    } else {
       //do your stuff
    }

});
```

Comment: These are different objects

Comment: My bad. I edited.

Comment: thanks i got it through this answer

Comment: but another way is available without more loops.

Comment: i want only, check array value and if exist then only change the quantity otherwise it should return same array.